# Server Error in '/' Application in Tridion

Tags: web-config, tridion

We have site that was working. When we moved to Tridion we get the following error:

> Configuration Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'SecureBinaries' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

> ```
>     <add verb="*" path="*.doc" type="SecureBinaries.fileHandler, SecureBinaries" />
> ```

Source File: *****\web.config    Line: 43

> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'SecureBinaries' could not be loaded.

**That is Line 43 above that causes the error.** Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add line 43 of your web.config to the question.  Could this SecureBinaries be a custom assembly?

Comment: That is line 43 above...with blue highlight. I tried to copy and paste more here and could not. I was wondering if an assembly is missing in the GAC. I am new to Tridion and it's been tricky.

Comment: Please add in the details of the assembly load trace.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. It is turned off now, the tough part is part of the team I am working with are in Europe, I am in U.S. I asked to have it turned on. My job is to analyze the bugs.

Comment: You'll need to figure out what that Assembly is doing. By its name, that's not a Tridion assembly at all.

Comment: Thanks Nuno. We are using Tridion on an existing site, creating components etc, but this assembly probably from the original.

Comment: Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'SecureBinaries' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 3):

Is the SecureBinaries assembly in the bin folder of your application or in the GAC on the server running the application?

If you add/enable the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog key the YSOD will show you where the attempt was made to load the SecureBinaries dll.

Cheers

Neil